# Node child_process await result

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, async-await, child-process

I have a async function which makes a `face_detection` command line call. It's working fine otherwise, but I can't make it to wait for the response. Here is my function:

```
async uploadedFile(@UploadedFile() file) {
    let isThereFace: boolean;
    const foo: child.ChildProcess = child.exec(
      `face_detection ${file.path}`,
      (error: child.ExecException, stdout: string, stderr: string) => {
        console.log(stdout.length);

        if (stdout.length > 0) {
          isThereFace = true;
        } else {
          isThereFace = false;
        }
        console.log(isThereFace);

        return isThereFace;
      },
    );

    console.log(file);

    const response = {
      filepath: file.path,
      filename: file.filename,
      isFaces: isThereFace,
    };
    console.log(response);

    return response;
  }
```

`isThereFace` in my response I return is always `undefined` because the response is sent to client before the response from `face_detection` is ready. How could I make this work?

Comment: Please consider using execSync (https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options) instead to execute your code synchronously.

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm executing sync operations in an async environment is highly discouraged because it blocks the whole node process ...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can either use the [`child_process.execSync`](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options) call, which will wait for the exec to finish. But executing sync calls is discouraged ...

Or you can wrap `child_process.exec` with a promise

```js
const result = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
   child.exec(
      `face_detection ${file.path}`,
      (error: child.ExecException, stdout: string, stderr: string) => {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
        } else {
          resolve(stdout); 
        }
      });
});
```

Answer (score 4):

I think you must convert child.exec into a Promise and use it with await. Otherwise the async function is not waiting for child.exec result.

To make it easy you can use Node util.promisify method:
https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original

```
import util from 'util';
const exec = util.promisify(child.exec);
const result = await exec(`my command`);
```

Comment: `child` value is unknown

Comment: It was a quick answer for the code exposed on first post.
To solve that, import the lib :)
import * as child from 'child_process';

Answer (score 0):

A one-liner that does it:

```
const execute = async (command: string) => await new Promise(resolve => exec(command, resolve))
const result = await execute(`my command`);
```

Comment: I tried this and it might work (it's waiting) but the result is null. I'm testing using the command, `java -version`. I also tested, `java --vesion`.

Comment: @1.21gigawatts, I was using it with a command where the return value didn't matter or was void. I think java version number is going to stdout. you might query google to see how to capture stdout  when using exec.

Comment: So what's the point of having a `result` if you don't capture the actual result of the underlying command? Furthermore, your approach will always *resolve* the promise, even if the underlying command returned an error and then the `result` ill be this error, ie your promise *resolves with an error* which is rather strange ...